# Maven zip artifact copy, unzip and rename

Tags: java, maven, groovy, maven-plugin

I have a maven module which is packaged as a zip with naming *my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip* using *maven-shade-plugin*.

Once the artifact has been installed into local maven repo, I need:

1. Copy zip to configured local folder.
2. Unzip archive.
3. Rename unzipped folder from *my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT* to *my-artifact*.

This process should be cross-platform working on Windows, Linux, MacOS machines.

I read that it could be accomplished by using:

1. *maven-dependency-plugin* plus another plugin
2. *maven-groovy-plugin*

What would the best way to implement such a flow? Any examples are very appreciated.

Comment: If you correctly define the dependency this artifact will automatically downloaded and cached in your local repository...So the question is why you need to unzip it? If it has been created by maven-shade-plugin it is usually a jar file which contains many classes ...so zip file is not a good idea...

Comment: My artifact is not a regular jar file, it's a zip that been used by talend enterprise studio. And for local development, I've implemented the flow to unzip built artifact and deployed to the talend studio. It's only for local development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for antrun in my opinion, the maven-dependency-plugin should do the trick:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>[your.group.id]</groupId>
                                <artifactId>my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT</artifactId>
                                <version>[your.version]</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/my-artifact/</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Regards,

Tom

Comment: almost works. The result of such configuration would be:

${project.basedir}/my-artifact/my-artifact-1.0-SNAPHOST/...{artifact_items}...

I do not need my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT in the path

Comment: Let me rephrase the issue. I need to set unpacked directory name. Haven't found it in the documentation.

Comment: Hmm ok, that won't work directly with maven-dependency-plugin afaik ... but the problem seems the directory in the Zip-Archive, i guess my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT is in there too? You could use the maven-assembly-plugin to create a zip-File without the path (using <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory> in the assembly-descriptor)

Comment: The artifact is a zip file itself. All module files are in my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip

I need to place unzip them into /mypath/my-artifact/...

Comment: Yes I got that. But with my example if you have a zipfile my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip\myFile.txt it would place myFile.txt under /my-artifact/myFile.txt ... if however you got a zipfile my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip\my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT\myFile.txt it would go to /my-artifact/my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT/myFile.txt. So, one solution would be to remove the path in the zip-file itself ...

Comment: Not exactly. Using your solution:
my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip/myFile.txt
will go to:
/my-artifact/my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT/myFile‌​.txt

Comment: Should be working as descriped (at least we're using it this way). I'd suggest you check the stucture of your zip-File, I bet there's a Folder my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT in there, not just the File(s).

Comment: you were totally right. My bad. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have a maven plugin that can execute Ant-Tasks. This tasks let you execute a lot of works. For example, to unzip a file:

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
               <tasks>
                  <unzip src="path/to/zip/file.zip" dest="path/to/unzip" />
               </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
               <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

You can check all availables task in the apache ant page (see references).

**Reference:**
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks

Comment: I'm struggling configuring artifact zip file path of unzip.src